# What is the recommended TFS structure.

Tags: tfs, project-reference, dll-reference

We are trying to move from our current source control to a TFS as a source control. Right now we have all projects as project references. Our organization is small and we have a lot of common projects that are used by various development teams and all teams update these projects as needed. When we migrate to TFS we are looking to use DLL references for these projects but I am wondering if that would make branching impossible and I am also concerned about is there a benefit of having DLL references to the projects that all teams in the company need to make changes to.

Could you please suggest, given our scenario, if it would be good idea to have DLL references to our common projects or to have project references. Any links to suggested readings would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the size of these projects and how often you make changes there, dll references are generaly used for 3rd party libs, if you own common projects are not often changed and/or changed by small/dedicated group of ppl then it may be benificial to treat them the same way, otherwise its better to have project references.

Im not sure why dll references would present branching problems ? You branch them just like any other code or project, if they dont differ per branch you can save yourself time on updates and keep them outside branch in single location.